# Adding additional windows search keywords to a single shortcut or executable

Tags: executable, windows-search

We have an executable file with an installer which generates shortcuts in the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` directory.

The name of the software is formatted `FOO-Bar`. We want users to be able to locate the executable in Windows search by typing `FOO Bar` or just `Bar`, but this does not seem to work due to the hyphen in the name. The hyphen cannot be removed due to specific style guidelines.

Is there a way to inform windows search that the executable or shortcut can be found by the other forms of the title? I know something similar is done with Visual Studio Code, where you can locate the same short cut with the search `code`, `vscode`, or `vs code`.

Comment: I assume the answer is no, but are you willing to do extra work to each individual file, like manually adding a shortcut to its Property?

Comment: Seems to be working for me (Windows 10, 11), I guess you'll have to be more specific as to version, search setup, language, etc. When I type "foo", FOO-Bar comes first, when I type "bar", "Game Bar" (from Windows) comes first, but FOO-Bar second. Note that with a shortcut, Windows remembers the shortcut name *and* the target file name. So if you have a "FOO-Bar" shortcut that points to say a "Fubar.exe", it should find it by FOO, BAR, and Fubar.

Comment: Windows 10/11 would be enough... I even settle for Windows 11 only. The most interesting part of the question is the VSCode example.. how can they do this?

Comment: vs code works because the actual application is called `Code.exe` but it is in a folder called `Microsoft VS Code` - both "vscode" and "vs code" work as searches simply because they contain the word "code".

Comment: @StefanEgli - they do nothing special, download inno setup, build this script (add some vscode.exe file as laid out in the .iss file) https://pastebin.com/raw/6Y8rn8Yu, copy the output in a Windows 10 or 11 box, and you'll see you can search by vs, code or vscode or "vs code". Note this works partly thanks to Windows Indexing turned on (doesn't fully answer in Windows Sandbox where this is off, for example)

Comment: That is not what I am seeing on my systems...

Comment: @StefanEgli - have you tried to build a setup with instructions I gave? How is your PC installed, you should see at least some of it, even w/o indexing service.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to inform windows search that the executable or
> shortcut can be found by the other forms of the title? I know
> something similar is done with Visual Studio Code, where you can
> locate the same short cut with the search code, vscode, or vs code.

vs code works like this because the actual application is called `Code.exe` but it is in a folder called `Microsoft VS Code` - both "vscode" and "vs code" work as searches simply because they contain the word "code".

Other than that you would need to specify the version of Windows, because in Windows 11 at least this is how it already works.

e.g.

I have a shortcut called Foo-Bar [image: shortcut]

I search for "Foo Bar"

[image]

I search for "Bar"

[image]

Also using the comments for the short-cut works, so perhaps this will work for you? Try adding comments to the shortcut with "Foo Bar" etc.

[image]

Searching for the comment "Bat"

[image]

Even just searching for the hyphen itself works...

[image]

Comment: Windows 10/11 is fine. I am most interested in adding a different keyword (like vscode vs code) and I did also try adding a keyword to the shortcut Comment field, but this does not seem to have an effect for a startmenu shortcut.

Comment: @StefanEgli I'm a bit confused, in windows 11 adding comments to the shortcut does make that a keyword in the start search. To clarify, vscode works simply because the exe is called "code" and it is in a folder called "Microsoft VS Code" - there is nothing special or unusual about it.

Comment: That is not what I am seeing on my systems... neither comment nor folder name seem to have any effect.

Comment: Not sure, that is how it works out of the box....maybe your Indexing is borked? Try running the "Search and Indexing" troubleshooter?

Answer (score 0):

Well, stating the obvious : create two shortcuts, one to match your style guide, one to match your requirement.